# How to solve for a Unit Vector

Tags: math, vector, linear-algebra

```
uvec1 = (vec3 - vec1).normalize3() 
uvec2 = (vec3 - vec2).normalize3()

   Vec normalize3()
   {
      double length = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
      return new Vec(x/length, y/length, z/length);      
   }
```

Given only uvec2, vec1, and vec2, is is possible to solve for uvec1?

Sample Data:

```
vec1 = (3994349.6104437034, -2525024.5798455356, 4270768.558174166, 1.0)    
vec2 = (3994350.7884981344, -2525023.416923353, 4270767.502702763, 1.0)    
vec3 = (3994403.673228261, -2525050.920923162, 4270738.823082169, 1.0) 
uvec1 = (0.8058476404228322, -0.3926341461126214, -0.44322455677835176, 1.0)
uvec2 = (0.7994702158645208, -0.415784076265458, -0.43355619689910574, 1.0)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write the code to do this?  What language?  Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to do this, and if so, how. This is not homework.

Obviously if I have vec1, vec2, and vec3 available , I know how to calculate uvec1 and uvec2. My question is, if I only have uvec2, vec1, and vec2 available, is it possible to calculate uvec1?

Comment: This question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, you have the following

```
u1 = (v3 - v1)/||v3 - v1||
u2 = (v3 - v2)/||v3 - v2||
```

You want to solve for `u1` given `v1`, `v2`, and `u2`, apparently without knowing `v3`. Let's write the first equation as

```
u1 = ((v3 - v2) + (v2 - v1))/||v3-v1||
```

substitute the bottom equation in:

```
u1 = (u2*||v3 - v2|| + (v2 - v1))/||v3 - v1||
```

This last equation seems to show that having a different `v3` will define different `u1` even if the values of `v1`, `v2`, and `u2` are the same. Hence `u1` can't be uniquely determined with just the values you gave.